# Event Tracking without creating Goal in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, seo

How to do event tracking and send data to Google Analytics without creating a Goal in Google Analytics.

e.g. If I have 6 image links on the homepage, I want to do event tracking and send data to GA that how many people clicked on which image/category. But don't want to create goal for it.

Comment: Events and goals are separate things. Goals can be created from events (called event goals) but events don't need to be part of a goal. You fire the events in the normal way and just don't configure event goals around them.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is tracking code attached to your image, you can see events at Google Analytics at Behaviour -> Event -> Top Events, there you will be able to see reports by event category / event label / event action. You don't need a goal to achieve so.